# HLS live streams not working in Safari on OS X El Capitan with the HTML 5 <video> tag

Tags: html, safari, html5-video, osx-elcapitan, http-live-streaming

I'm seeing a very strange issue where I'm able to view a live video stream over HLS (mpeg-TS as the container) on older versions of OS X, but not in the latest version (El Capitan).  I'm using Safari 9.0.1 in both scenarios.

Essentially, I have a trivial HTML 5 `<video>` tag, giving the live stream's URL as a source.  In older versions of OS X this plays without issue, but on `OS X 10.11.1` it will show *at best* one frame, and then not play.

Here is a small code snippet to reproduce, with a stream for testing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <body> 
    <video width="400" controls autoplay>
      <source src="http://204.101.47.140:8080/cameras/1eq0U31IYNNWUOss/live.m3u8?stream=3ddf9e2c-46f6-40a0-e010-272d1a058369">
    </video> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

There are no relevant errors visible in the browser console, and I've been able to reliably reproduce this working on OS X Mavericks/Yosemite, and not working on El Capitan across several machines.

What changes are required to the above code to make it work on Safari across all recent versions of OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your video source is not a valid HLS stream. It is an HLS/pseudo-streaming mix. The stream master resource (http://204.101.47.140:8080/cameras/1eq0U31IYNNWUOss/live.m3u8?stream=3ddf9e2c-46f6-40a0-e010-272d1a058369) is a valid HLS playlist that contains a single element. So far so good. However this element is not a finite piece of the whole video stream. It is a resource that when requested starts pseudo streaming the whole live stream.

This is not a valid HLS stream. I don't know which media server you use, if any, but it is not configured properly.

Comment: Interesting.  Your response definitely makes sense.  Thank you.  I have control of the media server, and the whole 'psuedo streaming live stream' setup is to reduce latency (rather than consistently fetching chunks for playing live).  It is strange that this only stopped being supported in the latest OS X release.  I can't find any documentation around adherence to the HLS spec being changed.

Comment: There is nothing in the HLS spec regarding pseudo streaming. My guess is that this is an implementation detail. Probably previous versions of OS X were passing the video stream along to the decoder immediately after receiving it from the network while latter versions first download a whole HLS segment and only then pass it to the decoder. QuickTime supports pseudo streaming so maybe Safari does too. Have you tried specifying the pseudo streaming resource as a `src` of the video element?

Comment: BTW this is becoming off-topic. Maybe you should answer another question: "HTTP pseudo streaming in Safari on El Capitan".